# How to make first two columns sticky in a table in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend, react-typescript

In a table want to make the first two **columns header sticky** along with their body

Answer (score 0):

**Sticky Table**

```
interface TableProps {
  data: Array<Array<string | number>>;
  headers: string[];
}

const StickyTable: React.FC<TableProps> = ({ data, headers }) => {
  return (
    <div className="table-container">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           {headers.map((header, index) => (
             <th key={index}>{header}</th>
           ))}
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         {data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <tr key={rowIndex}>
           {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
            <td key={cellIndex}>{cell}</td>
           ))}
          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
  )
 };
 export default StickyTable;
```

**Table.css**

```
.table-container {
  max-height: 400px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 8px;
 text-align: left;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
 position: sticky;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 z-index: 1;
}

th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2) {
 z-index: 2;
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const headers = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4'];

  const data = [
   ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4'],
    // Add more rows if needed
   ];
   
   return (
     <div>
      <StickyTable headers={headers} data={data} />
     </div>
   );
}
export default App;
```